# FTP timing out on Heroku

Tags: scala, heroku, ftp, apache-commons

Using Apache Commons [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) in a Scala application works as expected on my local machine, but always times out when running on Heroku. Relevant code:

```
val ftp = new FTPClient
ftp.connect(hostname)
val success = ftp.login(username, pw)
if (success) {
  ftp.changeWorkingDirectory(path)
  //a logging statement here WILL print
  val engine = ftp.initiateListParsing(ftp.printWorkingDirectory)
  //a logging statement here will NOT print
  while (engine.hasNext) {
    val files = engine.getNext(5)
    //do stuff with files
  }
}
```

By adding some loggings I've confirmed the client **is** successfully connecting, logging in, and changing the directory. But stops when trying to begin retrieving files (either via the above paged access or unpaged with `ftp.listFiles`) and throws a connection time out exception (after about 15 minutes).

Any reason the above code works fine locally but not on Heroku?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out FTP has two modes, [active and passive](http://slacksite.com/other/ftp.html), and Apache-Commons' [FTPClient](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-net/apidocs/org/apache/commons/net/ftp/FTPClient.html) defaults to active. Heroku's firewall presumably doesn't allow active FTP (which is why this was functioning properly locally but not once deployed) - changing to passive mode by adding `ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()` resolved the issue.