# How do I make a temporary file on heroku? Not resolved problem

Tags: java, spring-boot, heroku, ftp, file-transfer

I have an app hosted on Heroku.
It has a simple functionality to upload files on a ftp server.
Locally it works perfectly, 
but I have a problem with the same app deployed on heroku.
It throws an error when trying to save a file.

Actually it also saves it, but the file's size is 0 bytes
here is the code:

```
    public boolean fileUpload(MultipartFile file, String fileName) {
    try {
        FtpClient ftp = new FtpClient(ftpHost, ftpPort, ftpUser, ftpPassword);
        ftp.open();

        File tempFile = File.createTempFile(System.currentTimeMillis() + "tmp", "jpg");
        file.transferTo(tempFile );
        ftp.putFileToPath(tempFile , fileName);
        ftp.close();
        return true;
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        return false;
    }
}
```

I think that the problem is with this line:

```
File tempFile = File.createTempFile(System.currentTimeMillis() + "tmp", "jpg");
        file.transferTo(tempFile );
```

I have passed through all the questions according to the problem on StackOverflow
but I didn't get the working answer

I din't add any add-ons on heroku instead of logging.

Here is a log from that problem:

> Oct 08 01:53:04.527pm info app web.1 200 PORT command successful (xxx.xx.xx.xxx:xxxxx).
>
> Oct 08 01:53:04.528pm info app web.1 STOR 1602157983845A2.jpg
>
> Oct 08 01:53:04.636pm info app web.1 150 Opening BINARY mode data connection for '1602157983845A2.jpg'.
>
> Oct 08 01:53:33.706pm error heroku router req=0a0bbc10… at=error code=H12 desc="Request timeout"
> method=POST path="/add-graphic" host=xxxxxxx.herokuapp.com request_id=xxxxxxxx-xxxx-xxxx-xxxx-
> xxxxxxxxxxxx fwd="xx.xxx.xx.xxx" dyno=web.1 connect=0ms service=30889ms status=503 bytes=0
> protocol=https

After some more rearch of the problem, 
it seems that heroku dyno stucks on that line:

```
ftp.putFileToPath(tempFile , fileName);
```

the methot putFileToPath looks like that:

```
public void putFileToPath(File file, String path) throws IOException {
    ftp.storeFile(path, new FileInputStream(file));
}
```

Comment: The log shows clearly that it has a request timeout on the upload of the file. Heroku has an default timeout of 30 seconds. How big is the file you are trying to upload?

Comment: I was trying even a file that is 43kb

Comment: I would then advise you to remove all code from the method body and add it back in line by line to see what makes your heroku dyno freeze up.

Comment: I did what you say, it seems tat it stucks on tat method: ftp.putFileToPath(tempFile , fileName);

Comment: Which ftp client are you using?

Comment: import org.apache.commons.net.ftp.FTPClient;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add

```
ftp.enterLocalPassiveMode()
```

before

```
ftp.storeFile(path, new FileInputStream(file));
```

Background: [FTP timing out on Heroku](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19935068/ftp-timing-out-on-heroku)